# From a given Map to a json string (or JSONObject)

Tags: java, json, dictionary

In Java, I've these key/value pairs passed by post (for example):

```
form_id=undefined

frmb[0][cssClass]=input_text

frmb[0][required]=checked

frmb[0][values]=First Name

frmb[1][cssClass]=input_text

frmb[1][required]=checked

frmb[1][values]=Last Name

frmb[2][cssClass]=textarea

frmb[2][required]=undefined

frmb[2][values]=Bio

frmb[3][cssClass]=checkbox

frmb[3][required]=undefined

frmb[3][title]=What's on your pizza?

frmb[3][values][2][baseline]=undefined

frmb[3][values][2][value]=Extra Cheese

frmb[3][values][3][baselise]=undefined

frmb[3][values][3][value]=Pepperoni

frmb[3][values][4][baseline]=undefined

frmb[3][values][4][value]=Beef

frmb[4][cssClass]=radio

frmb[4][required]=undefined

frmb[4][title]=Do you like pizza?

frmb[4][values][2][baseline]=checked

frmb[4][values][2][value]=Yes

frmb[4][values][3][baseline]=undefined

frmb[4][values][3][value]=No

frmb[5][cssClass]=select

frmb[5][multiple]=checked

frmb[5][required]=checked

frmb[5][title]=Select a pizza type:

frmb[5][values][2][baseline]=checked

frmb[5][values][2][value]=Margherita

frmb[5][values][3][baseline]=undefined

frmb[5][values][3][value]=Napoli

frmb[5][values][4][baseline]=undefined

frmb[5][values][4][value]=Marinara
```

I've to create the following json:

```
[{"cssClass":"input_text","required":"checked","values":"First Name"},{"cssClass":"input_text","required":"checked","values":"Last Name"},{"cssClass":"textarea","required":"undefined","values":"Bio"},{"cssClass":"checkbox","required":"undefined","title":"What's on your pizza?","values":{"2":{"value":"Extra Cheese","baseline":"undefined"},"3":{"value":"Pepperoni","baseline":"undefined"},"4":{"value":"Beef","baseline":"undefined"}}},{"cssClass":"radio","required":"undefined","title":"Do you like pizza?","values":{"2":{"value":"Yes","baseline":"checked"},"3":{"value":"No","baseline":"undefined"}}},{"cssClass":"select","required":"checked","multiple":"checked","title":"Select a pizza type:","values":{"2":{"value":"Margherita","baseline":"checked"},"3":{"value":"Napoli","baseline":"undefined"},"4":{"value":"Marinara","baseline":"undefined"}}}]
```

How could I do?

I don't succeed in **parsing the keys**, grouping the elements which do part of the same JSONObject.

Comment: That's nice. It looks like a case for recursion. What have you tried?

Comment: @pst: Actually I was thinking something recursive, but I have not tried. I think I've to parse the keys, but what "structure" I have to create to use org.json to build the json?

Comment: Just walk it into the appropriate "JSONObjects" while recusing; the org.json version is more than sufficient for this. It looks like "is numeric key" *or* "values" they create a nested JSONObject (recurse) else, just map to property in current level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved by parsing the keys and by building the JSONObjects with the use of two temporary hashtables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library for this. It does not support serializaton of nested maps (I assume your output represents a nested map). You can write a custom serializer/deserializer or create your own serialization method following the instructions in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547739/how-to-serialize-a-map-of-a-map-with-gson)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
JSONArray jsonItems = new JSONArray();

for (int i = 0; i < frmb.size(); i++) {  

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();  
json.put("cssClass", frmb[i][cssClass]);  
json.put("required",frmb[i][required]);  
//put json object to json array  
jsonItems.put(json);   
}
```

Check [here](http://fundapass.blogspot.in/2012/06/j-ason-in-java-nbthis-is-not.html) for more details

Comment: Yes, so how to expand this to work over the nested structure?

Comment: As I haven't a JSONObject for each element passed by post, and as the keys are strings, I think I have to parse the keys in some way and build the JSONArray.