# HashMap to gson with maps as values

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to convert `HashMap` to `JSON` format using this kind of method:

```
public String JSObject(Object object) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(object);
}
```

But the problem is that when my HashMap has another HashMap as a key in the result I've got nothing in the JSON. Let's say I've  got something like this in Java:

```
put("key", HashMap);
```

after conversion my JSON looks like this:

```
"key" : {}
```

Want I want is obviously some kind of these:

```
"key" : {
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2" : "value2"
}
```

Is this becouse `toJson()` doesn't support more complicated `JSON`'s ? I think that's more probably me doing something wrong.

**@EDIT**

This is how I initialize the map:

```
put("key", new HashMap<String,String>(){{
                put("key1", "value1");
            }};
```

Comment: not possible... can we see that code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to serialize a Map of a Map with GSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547739/how-to-serialize-a-map-of-a-map-with-gson)

Comment: For me it is working good, are you sure, that your map is not empty?

Comment: hey, thanks for replies, i edited the question to show how I initialize the map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this:

```
final HashMap<String, String> value = new HashMap<String, String>(){{
    put("key1", "value1");
}};
```

You are creating new `AnonymousInnerClass` with `instance initializer`.

From `Gson docs` :

> Gson can also deserialize static nested classes. However, **Gson can not automatically deserialize the pure inner classes since their no-args constructor** also need a reference to the containing Object which is not available at the time of deserialization.

Just change you map to not use `instance initializer`:

```
final Map<String, String> value = new HashMap<>();
value.put("key", "value");
```

Comment: In the other words, I need to improve my method. Am I right?

Comment: Just don't use `instance initializer` because it creates anonymous inner classes which gson cannot serialize

Comment: Yes, that's the simplest solution. But I'm curious if I can change my `JSObject` method to let me use anonymous class

Comment: This does not look to be the issue. You are talking about *de*serialization while the question is asking about serialization.